# Musical language

Tags: riddle, word

Riddles are always funny, I would say this is rather easy:

> I am a language but you cannot speak me.
> You can increase me so that I am another language.
> You can make music with me.
> I am a grade, could be better but also worse.
> You cannot go faster than me.

Who am I?

Hint:

> I only consist of one letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> The letter "C"

I am a language but you cannot speak me.

> Refers to the [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), a language for coding that you can't speak

You can increase me so that I am another language.

> Adding a "+" to C results in "C+", another programming language that has since been [renamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS), and doing so again gives you [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)

You can make music with me

> "C" is a musical note

I am a grade, could be better but also worse.

> A grade of "C" is about the most average grade you could get

You can not go faster than me

> The [speed of light in a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) is denoted by "c" and is the fastest speed obtainable

Comment: The second one refers to the first one in some way.